# $G$ cyclic group of order $n$ and $g \in G$ generator; then $g^k$ is a generator iff $(k,n)=1$. Is this a valid argument?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Can I get the result in the title by simply noting that the map of $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ in itself, defined by $i \mapsto ki \pmod n$, is bijective if and only if $(k,n)=1$?

Comment: Or you can simply observe that $\gcd(k,n)=1$ implies $\exists \, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ka+nb=1$. Thus $$g^{1}=g^{ka+nb}=(g^{k})^a \cdot (g^{n})^{b}=(g^{k})^a.$$

Comment: @Anurag, Why does this imply $G=\langle g^k \rangle$?

Comment: We showed that $g \in \langle g^k \rangle$ so by closure $\langle g \rangle \subseteq \langle g^k \rangle$. This implies $G \subseteq \langle g^k \rangle$. The other containment is obvious.

Comment: I see. So $(k,n)=1 \Rightarrow G=\langle g^k \rangle$. Now, $G=\langle g^k \rangle \Rightarrow \forall j, \exists i \mid g^j=g^{ki} \Rightarrow i \mapsto ki \pmod n$ is surjective $\Rightarrow (k,n)=1$; this is how the argument in my post pop up. Am I wrong, or just overlooking something?